# How to set the OnText/OffText of a GridSwitchButtonEditControl of a SuperGridControl column?

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls, dotnetbar

I'm using this grid control on my project, and i want to be able to edit the ON OFF text of an entire column that has a GridSwitchButtonEditControl editortype.

The documentation of the component is over [here](http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=1265#GridColumn)

But i can't figure out how to set the default properties of the editor control of an entire column, nor the properties of a single row column editor (which according to the documentation are inherited from the column's editorcontrol).

Can someone please help me?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple way:

```
    SetSwitchText(column.EditControl as GridSwitchButtonEditControl);
    SetSwitchText(column.RenderControl as GridSwitchButtonEditControl);

    private void SetSwitchText(GridSwitchButtonEditControl ctl)
    {
        if (ctl != null)
        {
            ctl.OnText = "Yea";
            ctl.OffText = "Nay";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create your own  GridSwitchButtonEditControl class with custom values

   Private Class MyGridSwitchButtonEditControl
   Inherits GridSwitchButtonEditControl
   Public Sub New()
   StretchBehavior = StretchBehavior.HorizontalOnly
   OnText = "HELLO"
   OffText = "BYE"
   End Sub
   End Class
2. Create a sub to initialize the grid with your own Editor

   Private Sub InitializeGrid()
   Dim pnl = supergridcontrol1.PrimaryGrid
   Dim column As GridColumn = pnl.Columns("Column6")
   column.EditorType = GetType(MyGridSwitchButtonEditControl)
   End Sub

'3. On form Load call the InitializeGrid() to teach the grid on use your customized editor

```
Private Sub Fmain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
InitializeGrid()
End sub
```

This way your grid is initialized with your customized Editor. You can now see that OnText is "HELLO" and OffText is "BYE". 
Note that "Column6" is the name of the column where Editor is consumed (you can also use index)

Hope this helps

Greetings from Italy  :)